# How to make horizontal scrollbar always visible even if vertical scrollbar is at top

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

You can see, horizontal scrollbar is not visible when the vertical scrollbar is at the top. I need horizontal scrollbar so that it can be scrolled towards left and right side.

There is `<tr> and <td> tag` .

```
   <tr>
                        <th class="report-table-header">Error Description
                            <button style="height: 15px; width: 15px; background: url(img/copy.png); background-position: center; background-size: 15px; border: none; outline: none; margin: 2px;"
                                title="Copy to Clipboard" ng-click="copytoclipboard(summaryonlyerror)">
                            </button>
                        </th>
                        <td colspan="4"><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;overflow: auto;">
                            <pre  midwayclickable="summaryonlyerror" midwayclickabledata="lbadetails" midwayclickablecanshow="(testinfo.adapter == 'Card') ? true : false"></pre>
                            <!--ng-bind-html="summaryonlyerror | clickable: (testinfo.adapter == 'Card' ? true : false):lbadetails"-->
                        </div></td>
                    </tr>
```

[image: screenshot1 -> no horizontal bar here]

[image: screenshot 2- horizontal scroll bar is visible when vertical scrollbar reaches the bottom]